# sending emails android no waiting with scheduling

Tags: android

I need help
I develop an application on Android smartphone that must send emails, "without waiting", to warn, some time in advance, the wearer of the smartphone to restart the application to do an action. The email therefore acts as a reminder. The message sent, the application is closed until the action of the user who will do an action on the application. The holder of the smartphone is the only person involved.
I used, as a trial, the following code but I need to add an ability to send emails without waiting and scheduling for the display of the message.
The use of native functions is not easy with Maui I did not succeed. The code sought must be light because the application is intended for small Android smartphones (for example pixel5 .....).
Do you have any ideas or existing code?

```
   if (Sms.Default.IsComposeSupported)
   {
        try 
        {  
        string[] recipients = new[] { "X-XXX-XXX-XXXX" };
        string text = "Vous avez un RDV avec " + output[0] + "\n" + " le " + output[1] + "\n" + "entre " + output[2] + " et " + output[3];

        var message = new SmsMessage(text, recipients);

        await Sms.Default.ComposeAsync(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString()); }
   }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That code is never going to send an email, it attempts to send a text.  Which is a different thing.  A mobile app and email are a bad choice anyway, as to send an email you have to either know the SMTP server, username, and password, or you need to open up another app that does and have the user send the actual email.  Directly sending email isn't really done, because nobody is going to trust your app with that password.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer and you are right I wrote email instead of SMS but my need is to send sms no-wait and delayed. I was thinking about using the Message app on Android.
A thousand apologies